# Get TBox Axioms with OWL API

Tags: owl, ontology, owl-api

I'm working with a OWL API 3 / Pellet / SPARQL-DL stack and want to read the asserted TBox axioms of a certain class from an ontology.

I can easily access the axioms with OWL API. However, the OWLClassAxiom just provides function to access the signature without the connections. I.e. I want to know to which Class a ObjectProperty is assigned to. All I can retrieve is a set of all elements in the signature, without their connection.

It seems that OWL API does not really support working with given axioms on a class level well (Reading, not adding.) Or am I missing something? Any other ideas how to achieve that? (With whatever tools.)

Concrete Example: Pizza hasBase some PizzaTopping. I want to retrieve the value "PizzaTopping" by specifying Pizza and hasBase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Pizza is a class, then

Pizza hasBase some PizzaTopping

isn't a legal axiom.  What you probably actually have is

Pizza subClassof hasBase some PizzaTopping

That means that every *instance* of Pizza is related to some *instance* of PizzaTopping by the hasBase property.  The axiom is a subclass axiom, so you'd want to retrieve an instance of [OWLSubClassOfAxiom](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLSubClassOfAxiom.html), (which is a subclass of [OWLClassAxiom](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLClassAxiom.html)).

In this case, if you have a reference to the [OWLClass](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLClass.html) for Pizza, then  you could use [OWLClass#getSuperclasses()](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLClass.html#getSuperClasses%28org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology%29) to get a list of superclass expressions.  One of them would be an [OWLObjectSomeValuesFrom](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLObjectSomeValuesFrom.html) expression for **(hasBase some PizzaTopping)**.  You'd have to look for the ones of that type, and then examine the property that it is a restriction on.

That said, your stated goal

> to know to which Class a ObjectProperty is assigned to

doesn't quite match  up with the OWL model.  Object properties (and data properties) don't "belong" to classes in OWL.  You can use subclass axioms and property restrictions, like above, to say that members of a class must have a value for a particular property,

Comment: Right, the only thing you could do easily is to get for all axioms you're interested in the properties in the signature, but depending on the axiom type this might not be what you want. An `OWLAxiomVisitor` might be the way to go...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the flaws in my logic, great answer. I got it working. However, I still don't like the access of the axiom parts. All there is is "getXInSignature" which just returns a set. This is useless if you have a composition (e.g. intersection of two somevaluesfrom) - I need to manually go through the subaxioms. Maybe my use case is very specific or I still didn't got it completely. But anyhow, it works now! @AKSW is it possible to use the visitor just for axioms of a certain class or would it go through the whole ontology?

Comment: @nick There's `getProperty()` on the OWL Object Some Values From Axiom. You don't have to use getXInSignature methods. That said, AKSW'S suggestion to look into axiom visitors would probably help a lot.

Comment: @nick Either you implement only the `visit()` methods for your axiom types, or you apply the visitor only of the axioms that you have selected before by some given axiom types. Both should work.